# parsing GML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I am having an issue where my code only works sometimes and I'm hoping someone with more expertise can examine what I am doing incorrectly. Based on some reading, it appears that querying the tag directly as a Descendants was the easiest way to get my information, but i'm starting to realize that it may not have been the best way.

My Code:

```
XDocument GMLfile = XDocument.Load(thefile.gml);
XNamespace gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";

//--------------------------------------------------
var coordquery = from coords in GMLfile.Descendants(gml + "coordinates") select coords.Value;

foreach (var coords in coordquery)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(coords);
}
```

The Behavior/problem:

It will parse some files correctly and grab all of the horizontally aligned coords, but other files it will just simply grab the first set of comma separated coords and stop at the space delimiter.

Sample GML file content:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ogr:FeatureCollection
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://ogr.maptools.org/ zprocess.xsd"
     xmlns:ogr="http://ogr.maptools.org/"
     xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Box>
      <gml:coord><gml:X>-102.3542101578954</gml:X><gml:Y>48.27850492279583</gml:Y></gml:coord>
      <gml:coord><gml:X>-100.6813690821913</gml:X><gml:Y>48.46080715637999</gml:Y></gml:coord>
    </gml:Box>
  </gml:boundedBy>

  <gml:featureMember>
    <ogr:Dak fid="F0">
      <ogr:geometryProperty><gml:Polygon><gml:outerBoundaryIs><gml:LinearRing><gml:coordinates>-100.68704653821987,48.450386310687691 -100.68707054736575,48.450298060122066 -100.68710318142342,48.450211043099841 -100.68714430060783,48.450125632233721</gml:coordinates></gml:LinearRing></gml:outerBoundaryIs></gml:Polygon></ogr:geometryProperty>
      <ogr:Id>0</ogr:Id>
      <ogr:Dist>500.00000000000</ogr:Dist>
    </ogr:Dak>
  </gml:featureMember>
</ogr:FeatureCollection>
```

If anyone would care to define a better way to do this or elaborate on how to correctly use LINQ to XML when parsing sections of a XML, I would be forever thankful!

Kind Regards,
-GeekSmurf

Comment: What exactly you want to fetch from xml file?

Comment: All data between the tags <gml:coordinates> ...</gml:coordinates>

Comment: @GeekSmurf is the GML file _simply_ grab the first set of comma separated coords ?

Comment: @Thirisangu my example syntax only would grab the first set of "coordinates" in the foreach loop and then stop, is what i meant to say. I wanted it to parse all the coordinates in between the <gml:coordinates> ...</gml:coordinates> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
XNamespace gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";

var qry = xDoc.Root
         .Elements(gml + "boundedBy")
         .Elements(gml + "Box")
         .Elements(gml + "coord")
         .Select(a=>new
              {
                  x=a.Element(gml + "X").Value,
                  y=a.Element(gml + "Y").Value
               });
```

Above query returs:

```
x                    y
-102.3542101578954   48.27850492279583 
-100.6813690821913   48.46080715637999
```

Comment: Thank you for that, it helped me to see the approach you are using, but I am still not having any success on the Coordinates section. Make note that there's 2 different sections. coord and **coordinates**. I am trying to retrieve the coordinates section.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only **coordinates**:

```
        XDocument xd = XDocument.Load("5.xml");
        XNamespace gml = "http://www.opengis.net/gml";

        var xy = xd.Root
            .Descendants(gml + "coordinates")
            .Select(y => y.Value.Split(' ').Select(z => z.Split(','))
                            .Select(z => new { X = z[0], Y = z[1] }).ToArray())
            .Single();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", 
            xy.Select(z => string.Format("X:{0}\tY:{1}\t", z.X, z.Y))));
```

Out:

```
X:-100.68704653821987   Y:48.450386310687691
X:-100.68707054736575   Y:48.450298060122066
X:-100.68710318142342   Y:48.450211043099841
X:-100.68714430060783   Y:48.450125632233721
```

If you need to get anything else, you need show how to look like a conclusion

Comment: Foggy , thank you for taking the time to write this up. Can you please help me understand the logic of the code? I am very novice at C# programming and this would help immensely to understand how this code works. I also need to make the results dump to a listBox through a loop, so understanding what you did would also help with that.

Comment: @GeekSmurf Written comments may help: http://pastebin.com/0rTCzjaV  Would write more text, but my English is very bad.  If you show me how looks your form, I tried to write the code that you need